# Feedback modal upon exiting beta

Tags: modal-windows

We're releasing a new feature which will be beta tested. We're exploring ways in which we can collect feedback about the feature and one way was to surface a modal if the user decides to opt-out of the beta. At this point, we would display a modal, with 2 questions, both optional.

[image]

If the user clicks "Submit feedback" the form data will be submitted and the user would be taken to the 'old' service. If the user clicks "Cancel" the modal will close and they will remain in the beta.

My question is, is it acceptable to surface a feedback modal at this point?, and should I include a third button which would allow the user to exit the beta without giving feedback?

Comment: If you _do_ have the "_What didn't you like..._" question at this point, _please_ add either an "_Other..._" option, with a text-box to enter what wasn't liked, or at least a "_None of the above_" option. Even if such feedback is anonymously aggregated, I dislike being forced to choose a ready-made option if none of them really apply.

Answer (score 1):

This approach seems a bit cumbersome to me. If the user is opting out of a certain feature, layout or style, they are not happy or comfortable with it. An intrusive pop-up like this would increase their frustration.

### Let the user opt-out without asking for feedback. Instead, use a banner notification to nudge the user for it once the action is complete.

This would be non-intrusive and would still draw the user's attention. Also, it would make it easier for you and the user to handle the opt-out process. Just a simple,

> "This would take you back to the old layout/feature/design. Are you
>   sure about opting-out of the beta version?"

would do the trick. An easy "Yes" or "No" works much better than the current approach

---

<sub>Example of a banner notification</sub>

[image: Banner notification in Slack]